# Purpose of ような in last sentence about Sony and Honda's electric car plans

Tags: grammar

I was reading this article today and the last sentence states:

> 新しい会社が、今までの車の考え方を大きく変えることができる**ような**電気自動車をつくっていくのか注目が集まっています。
>
> My translation: The new company has been getting (gathering) attention on whether (or not) going out and making this electric car can greatly change the way we current think about cars.

What I don't understand why the `ような` is needed. It seems like not having would result in the same meaning. What is it doing or what nuisance it provides? It seems like not having would

Article:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013857731000/k10013857731000.html

Comment: This seems related: [Meaning of ような when it is not decribing likeness/appearance](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94642/43676)

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29042/45489